# Contour integral of a positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, contour-integration, positive-definite

I need to prove the following proposition:

---

Assume that $H\left(  \lambda\right) \in\mathbb{R}^{\left(  n-1\right)
\times\left(  n-1\right)  }$ is a matrix function such that

$$H=H^{T}=\frac
{1}{2\pi\mathbf{i}}%
%TCIMACRO{\toint \nolimits_{C}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\textstyle\oint\nolimits_{C}}
%EndExpansion
H\left(  \lambda\right)  d\lambda \succ 0$$

and let $D_{1} = \mbox{diag}\left( d_{2},\ldots,d_{n}\right)$ and $D_{2} = \mbox{diag} \left(  d_{1},\ldots,d_{n-1}\right)  $
with $d_{i}>0$.
Then,

$$ \frac {1}{2\pi\mathbf{i}}%TCIMACRO{\toint \nolimits_{C}}%
%BeginExpansion
{\textstyle\oint\nolimits_{C}}
%EndExpansion
\left(  J\left(  \lambda\right)  ^{-1}D_{1}J\left(  \lambda\right)  \right)
H\left(  \lambda\right)  \left(  J\left(  -\lambda^{-1}\right)  D_{2}J\left(
-\lambda^{-1}\right)  ^{-1}\right)  \succ 0$$

where $J\left(\lambda\right) \in\mathbb{R}^{n-1 \times n-1}$ is a Jordan
block with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $C$ is a contour including the origin.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you the case $n = 2$?